# How can a require.js plugin call parentRequire relative to the baseURL?

Tags: requirejs, typescript

I'm using require-ts (https://github.com/iammerrick/require-ts) to import a typescript file with require.js. I need to import several .d.ts files to satisfy the compiler. When I specify the declarations inside my require.config, they are resolved relative to the module importing them. This is because require-ts calls parentRequire on the declarations. However, I want to resolve the declarations globally, relative to my baseURL, as the definitions have nothing to do with the specific module. What is the best way to do this? I'm absolutely fine with modifying the require-ts if that is what's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per module id / resource URI resolution rules, the resource ID is NOT resolved relative the current container/module, unless that resource ID starts with "." char. ("./*" or "../*")

I am not aware of formal AMD / RequireJS article on ID normalization / resolution, but the following two may help:

[module ID resolution / normalization](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/amd#normalizing-module-identifiers)

[general language on `define` statement](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD)

In other words, "stop using `.` as the starting char of the resource and the resource should be resolved against the AMD tree root."